# SQL List all rows first find the row with oldest timestamp and the group rows with same id together

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I use php, mysql and html together to show a table.
But I want to sort the items by timestamp and group the items with same id together.
Example:

```
Unsorted table:

    timestamp       id      name        description

    14:02           2       Hans        Is very nice!
    12:01           3       Jürgen      Is very bad!
    10:03           2       Hans        Again good.
    11:08           6       Anna        BAD!
    06:09           11      Peter       Good.

Right sorted table:

timestamp       id      name        description

06:09           11      Peter       Good.
10:03           2       Hans        Again good.
14:02           2       Hans        Is very nice!
11:08           6       Anna        BAD!
12:01           3       Jürgen      Is very bad!

Bad sorted table:

timestamp       id      name        description

06:09           11      Peter       Good.
10:03           2       Hans        Again good.
11:08           6       Anna        BAD!
12:01           3       Jürgen      Is very bad!
14:02           2       Hans        Is very nice!
```

I have following but don't work:

```
SELECT * FROM fehlerfilm ORDER BY timestamp, imdb_id
```

I get the Bad sorted table.

I want the at the end all items!
The process:

- SELECT all and look for the item with the oldest TIMESTAMP Is there a
  item with same ID? -> If yes group it next to the oldest item (equal which TIMESTAMP). -> If
  no look for the 2nd oldest item  And again the process

Comment: what you need isn't possible. per your condition you can order by timestamps first and if there are ties it would be ordered by id. You can't do both at the same time.

Comment: This seems to be a wasted duplicate.  I think the other one should have been marked duplicate of this.

Answer (score 1):

The derived table has a correlated sub-query which returns each imdb_id's lowest timestamp. Order by that column:

```
SELECT timestamp, id, name, description
from
(
    select f1.*, (select min(timestamp) from fehlerfilm f2
                  where f2.imdb_id = f1.imdb_id) as mintime
    from fehlerfilm f1
)
ORDER BY mintime, imdb_id, timestamp
```

Comment: I create the table with a foreach loop!:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score -2):

you can use following query which will group by id and order by time stamp descending order if you want recent data first.

SELECT * FROM fehlerfilm group by id ORDER BY timestamp desc

Comment: This wouldn't work because when you do GROUP BY you can only SELECT whatever is in the GROUP BY.  Your statement would come up with an error.